# Is it possible to use the mysql database of pimcore 4.5 for pimcore 5.6?

Tags: database, pimcore, pimcore-v5

Is it possible to use the mysql database of pimcore 4.5 for pimcore 5.6?

The reason is I just want to upload my data such as (documents, assets, etc…) from 4.5 database into 5.6 database without having to perform the pimcore 5 migration.

Answer (score 2):

No, this won't work. Even though many database tables stayed the same in these 2 versions, if you want to use Pimcore 5.6 you have to do an upgrade, which will also automatically migrate database for you.